# web2py deployment on dotcloud

Tags: wsgi, web2py, uwsgi, dotcloud

Has anyone managed to deploy web2py app on dotcloud using their latest CLI?

I've tried following their old doc: http://olddocs.dotcloud.com/tutorials/web2py, to deploy the standard web2py. It just doesn't work for me - it gives me "uWSGI Error wsgi application not found" when I go to the app url. I use the following setup:

```
web2pyapp/
  back/
    web2py/
    wsgi.py -> ./web2py/wsgihandler.py
  dotcloud.yml
```

and inside dotcloud.yml:

```
www:
  approot: back
  type: python
db:
  type: postgresql
```

the linked wsgi.py links to the original wsgihandler.py that comes with web2py, as suggested by dotcloud doc.

Comment: Are you getting that error in your log files, or when you go to your url in a web browser? I would ssh into your application container and look at /var/log/supervisor/ and all of the logs to see what they say. you can get the same results by running this command. dotcloud logs myapp.www where myapp is what you called your app.